# How to automatically install 3rd party frameworks from Podspec

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Im a beginner in creating my own framework. I was able to follow instructions in creating Private Pods. I have created two Repos, one for Podspecs repo, and one for the Pod(PodA) im trying to make. I have done proper pushing of PodA to Podspecs repo, proper tagging, and proper Podspecs file.

PodA has a dependency on a public 3rd party framework.
So, in my Podspecs, i add

`s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'`

In MainApp Podfile

```
source '<Private Pod URL>'

target 'MyAppName' do   

    use_frameworks!    
    pod 'PodA'

end
```

When I try to call pod install on MyAppName directory, I get error

```
Unable to find a specification for 'Alamofire (= 5.0.0-rc.3)' depended upon by 'PodA'
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:
PodA is the dummy name of the Pod im trying to make

Edit: Add Podspecs file. Changed summary, description, and homepage

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'TestPrivatePod1'
  s.version          = '0.2.2'
  s.summary          = 'Dummy summary.'

  s.description      = <<-DESC
            "Dummy Description."
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'http://www.google.com/'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'vicWT' => 'vic@worktable.sg' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/vicWT/TestPrivatePod1.git', :tag => '0.2.2' }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'


  s.source_files = 'TestPrivatePod1/Classes/**/*'
  s.swift_version = '5'
  s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'


end
```

Edit: 
Removed source  'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'

Edit: Fix syntax error from  `s.dependency 'Alamofire', '5.0.0-rc.3` to `s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3`

Edit: Add TestPrivatePod1 images

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is `PodA`?

Comment: It is the name of the Pod im trying to make. Sorry I should have put that in detail. Will Edit post. That is just a dummy name

Comment: No, can you actually share the name of the pod, I know that it's a dummy pod name, but I need to know what is the pod and why is `Alamofire` dependent on it otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Please see edited post. It includes the real name of the Private Pod. TestPrivatePod1

Comment: I have made the repo public, just so if you want to go see that repo, but I would put it back to private after the issue gets resolved

Comment: did you specify the platform in your app podfile? and why did you added source '<Private Pod URL>'
source  'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'
lines in you podfile?

Comment: The guides/tutorials I have read didn't require to specify the platform.  I missed, source  'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'. I have deleted that now in my MainApp Podfile. I have that before because I tried to call pod 'Alamofire' in my MainApp Podfile, but I understand I should not have to, because it is included as dependency already.

Comment: Ok Please remove it from your question as well because it confused for the users. And did you try my updated answer. Please let me know I am here to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Daljeet. Edited post to remove source  'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git' in podfile. About the updated answer, do u mean to uncomment this line ```# platform :ios, '12.0'``` ? Which is on top of the podfile? Sorry, Im not too knowledgable about this. Thanks again

Comment: No I am saying replace s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3' in your podspec file.

Comment: It already has.  See above "PodA has a dependency on a public 3rd party framework. So, in my Podspecs, i add

s.dependency 'Alamofire', '5.0.0-rc.3'"

Comment: I told you to change '5.0.0-rc.3 to '~> 5.0.0-rc.3' . Please check my answer

Comment: Yeah, im sorry about that, I didnt notice. I understand you r the first who mentioned that answer, once error gets resolved, the check answer is rightfully on your credit. However, even though I have corrected the syntax, I am still encountering  the error. Please see discussion below. Thanks

Comment: Yes I checked I think you are one step ahead to solve this issue. after doing that could you please run the same commands again and check. Also please mention platform version in your mainApp podfile as I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I actually have done that earlier after I have corrected the syntax error but without the platform version. Now I added the platform version and entered ```pod repo remove master``` , error appears ```repo master does not exist```.   ```pod setup``` ```pod update``` Same error still shows.. Then, I decided on entering these ```pod deintegrate
pod clean
rm Podfile``` Just ttrying to clean things up. But still same error appears after adding the Podfile on mainApp again. even though the podfile has platform version,   and source url

Comment: can you remove your cocoapod and install again. Run rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master and then sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: After entering those two commands, then podinstall, same error appears ```[!] Unable to find a specification for `Alamofire (~> 5.0.0-rc.3)` depended upon by `TestPrivatePod1`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.```

Comment: could you please comment pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.9' and try.

Comment: same error ```[!] Unable to find a specification for `Alamofire (~> 4.9)` depended upon by `TestPrivatePod1```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod update
```

Also change your dependecy in podfile like below.

```
s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'
```

And specify platfor version in your mainApp podfile:

```
 platform :ios, '10.3'
```

In case above does not work please run the following commands to install cocoapod again:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Please comment  `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.9'` from podfile of your project **TestPrivatePod1**.

Comment: can your share your PodA podspec file? or I have edited my answer please check.

Comment: Edited post to include Podspecs file

Comment: Please try with another version 'Alamofire', '~> 4.9' and check

Comment: Same error, ```[!] Unable to find a specification for `Alamofire (~> 4.9)` depended upon by `TestPrivatePod1`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the syntax you've used to specify the version of the dependency?

To something like:

```
s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'
```

Notice the extra symbols used before specifying the version number? Cocoapods recommends the use of optimistic version indicator i.e: `~>`

[Reference](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency)

Do let me know if it still doesn't work...

Comment: Thanks..  I missed that.. I have changed it to ```s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'``` . But still the error shows ```[!] Unable to find a specification for `Alamofire (~> 5.0.0-rc.3)` depended upon by `TestPrivatePod1`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile. ```

Comment: Okay, this error is normal. Can you try doing `pod repo update` on the terminal?

Comment: After entering ```pod repo update``` then ```pod install```, same error appears

Comment: `pod repo update` and `pod install` went successfully? I mean, did you see any error messages on the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are misunderstanding how this all works. Cocoapods gets the definition of the pods from a spec repo, this is `source` in the Podfile, and it's **not** the repository for a single pod. The default spec repo is `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`, you need to add this to your Podfile if you want to be able to use any public pods, like Alamofire.

Adding your private repo as a URL makes no sense because it's not a repository containing multiple specs, it's just the repo for a pod.

I think something like this might work:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'MyAppName' do   

    use_frameworks!    
    pod 'PodA', :git => '<Private Pod URL>'

end
```

If that doesn't, then you'll have to create your own spec repository that contains the definition of your pod. I won't cover it, [but there are a lot of resources about that.](https://medium.com/@shahabejaz/create-and-distribute-private-libraries-with-cocoapods-5b6507b57a03)

Comment: do u mean something like this?  ```source 'https://github.com/vicWT/PodSpecsRepoPrivate.git'```

Comment: Nope, add the default pod spec repo along with your own private one. You can have more than one repo.

Comment: Im sorry, i dont understand, what do u mean by default pod spec? and private one? My understanding is the 'private' one is the `TestPrivatePod1`, and the default pod spec is `TestPrivatePod1.podspec` , is this correct? Please see images above

Comment: When I added ```source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git``` , and ```pod 'TestPrivatePod1', :git => 'https://github.com/vicWT/PodSpecsRepoPrivate.git'``` , then ```pod install```,   it seemed like it was just loading, I had to terminate terminal..